# Magento 2: How to change scope of 'visibility' attribute programmatically?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

When i edit the visibility attribute from admin and press save, It gets stuck in ajax loader and does not save that attribute. I simply wants to change the scope from store view to global. Is there any way to achieve this programmatically or by using some modification in db directly?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the logs for errors? (magento and php logs)

Comment: I did not find any error in magento logs. But status of ajax is '503 service unavailable'.

Comment: That indicates there's a PHP error. You need to check Apache / Nginx / PHP error logs